# Convert Window Onload function to non blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, onload-event

can anyone help me to convert this following function so that it wont block the page loading. I read that `$(window).load` function is bad but I'm using [FlexiSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) which uses `$(window).load`. I have no idea how to outrun this.

Here is the code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How does that block the page loading? It the `load` event occurs after the page has loaded.

Comment: Yes thats what I want. To load the event after the page is loaded. So how do I do that. I read an article many months ago (not remember properly) that window load even is actually block pageloading. So I want it to load the element after the page completes loading.

Comment: you read the article wrong

Comment: Thanks man for the reply. You have cleared my doubt about this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`.